Adding a Glow Effect to the Exterior of an Image
Consider the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=13cm]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

which produces

QUESTION: How may I add a glow effect to the exterior of the above image? In this case, the image is rectangular in shape (and hence, a rectangular glow is desired); but if possible, I would like to be able to extend the technique to non-geometrically shaped images as well.
Thank you.

Can you add a sketch how the result should look like?

I guess for the above image. the aurora would be rectangularly shaped and emanate just a little from the rectangular image; however, my ultimate goal would be to do such a thing for non-geometrically shaped images (i.e., produce non-geometrically shaped auroras conforming to the shape of the actual image.)

Tikz has a couple of options for shadows - hard to tell if that's what you are looking for without seeing an example.

For a relatively large image why prevent it being on a page on is own?

@DavidCarlisle Latex often wastes a lot of space when it does that. I know you can tweak things in other ways, but just prohibiting it making a float page is easier. Plus, in this case the bounding box is going to be unreliable in all probability.

There's the shadows.blur library which creates blur shadows for any shape - as opposed to the built-in shadows which provides blurring only for circles and (possibly?) ellipses. I'm not sure this is exactly a 'glow' but perhaps it provides a starting point.
[I tried to provide an image but the conversion alters the shadow so that it looks entirely non-shadow like!]
In the example, the effect is deliberately exaggerated. scale=1.1 is clearly too large for a subtle anything.
\documentclass[border=25pt,tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719111/
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [blur shadow={shadow xshift=0pt,shadow blur radius=5ex,shadow yshift=0pt,shadow scale=1.1,shadow blur steps=20}] {\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=13cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

As far as I can tell, the library has the standard Ford philosophy: you can have any colour of blur shadow you like, as long as it is black. You can alter the fill colour, but it only changes what the black is mixed with. That is, you end up with an entirely opaque result. If the library's author is active, you could request an update to provide an option for the colour as it should not be a difficult change to make.
Alternatively, after loading the library, you could simply redefine things to use the colour of your choosing. Unfortunately, black is hard-coded in a number of places, so this would mean duplicating large chunks of the code.
Another option would be to just make a copy of the library, shadows.myblur, say, and alter black to use mycolour, which you could then define or redefine at will.

Many thanks for this answer.
